# Why am I experiencing CORS issue when trying to redirect checkout page to Stripe checkout in React application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement a Stripe checkout in my React application. Currently my "Basket" page contains a checkout button which calls the following form submit -

```
const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
        method: 'POST',
        // mode: "no-cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({productId}),
      });
  
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log('Request sent successfully');
      } else {
        console.log('Request failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error occurred during the request', error);
    }
  }
```

This calls on my API

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
    // Get the selected product ID from the frontend
    const { productId } = req.body;

    console.log(productId)

    // Define a mapping of product IDs to prices
    const priceMap = {
        bricky_id: 'price_1NA7O1JVu65LdnVcBljr473q',
        sub_id: 'price_1NA64tJVu65LdnVcfgUwbhUA',
        // Add more product IDs and their corresponding prices here
      };
    
    //   Get the price based on the selected product ID
      const price = priceMap[productId];

      console.log(price);
    
      if (!price) {
        // Handle invalid product ID
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid product selected' });
      }
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
        {
            price: price,
            quantity: 1,
        },
        {
            price: 'price_1NA64tJVu65LdnVcfgUwbhUA',
            quantity: 1
        }
    ],
    mode: 'subscription',
    success_url: `http://localhost:4000/order-success`,
    cancel_url: `http://localhost:4000/order-preview`,
});
res.redirect(303, session.url);
// res.redirect({url: session.url});
// res.redirect(session.url);
});
```

When I make a simple call without anything in the req.body I get the redirect to the 3rd party stripe checkout page, however once I pass details into the req body I get the following CORS errors in browser -

Access to fetch at 'https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_b1SYlrHX7s9b3q2o08lxTvWtMvkV7UJ1ifRvv6tzoHMSGCMIygdCDm9hXD#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWjA0Szxpf2RPU3AzMElha1NmbFRjR3N9PU5dS1ZDbnJwQDJqX2lVb1IzM048TDFgQ2ZWYW5rbkpqXHA3PDVLYndCTnRVTnxAPTRyaH1dQ0djNTxvTTV1NFJQNTVRVlVXTW1LVycpJ2N3amhWYHdzYHcnP3F3cGApJ2lkfGpwcVF8dWAnPydocGlxbFpscWBoJyknYGtkZ2lgVWlkZmBtamlhYHd2Jz9xd3BgeCUl' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/create-checkout-session') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

OrderPreview.js:11     GET https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_b1SYlrHX7s9b3q2o08lxTvWtMvkV7UJ1ifRvv6tzoHMSGCMIygdCDm9hXD net::ERR_FAILED

My React application is currently using "proxy": "http://localhost:4000", for requests to the backend.

I am trying to pass the item information from the FE to BE and using that to redirect to the correct page in stripe however CORS is blocking the request.

I have added the following to my server file,

```
app.use(cors())
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
  });
```

I have also tried various formats of the response which I have left commented out.
// res.redirect({url: session.url});
// res.redirect(session.url);

I feel like I am misunderstanding the issue as the redirect worked prior to passing information from front-back. I am wondering if the issue is to do with the proxy?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you're using React, try removing the server-side redirect and switch to a client-side redirect. Just have /create-checkout-session return a 200 response with the session.url in the response body. Then do a client side redirect to that URL with window.location.href = <session url>;

Comment: That works perfectly thank you, as an aside is this considered bad practice at all? Generally speaking using window.location.href seems too heavy handed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @codename_duchess said try to move the redirect in the front and try also to add a content type to your post request:

```
const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
e.preventDefault();
try {
const response = await fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({productId}),
});

if (response.ok) {
  console.log('Request sent successfully');

  // Fetch the session URL from the response
  const { url } = await response.json();

  // Redirect the user to the Stripe Checkout page
  window.location.href = url;
 } else {
   console.log('Request failed');
  }
}catch (error) {
  console.log('Error occurred during the request', error);
 }
```

}